Lock screen when USB device is removed
I would like to have a udev rule that will lock my screen when Nitrokey HSM is removed.
So I run udevadm monitor --property, pull out Nitrokey USB and see a bunch of text, but also:
ACTION=remove
DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:08.1/0000:08:00.4/usb5/5-2
SUBSYSTEM=usb
DEVNAME=/dev/bus/usb/005/083
DEVTYPE=usb_device
PRODUCT=20a0/42b2/108

So I created new .rules file:
sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/70-lockscreen.rules
and added this:
ACTION=="remove", ATTRS{PRODUCT}=="20a0/42b2/108", RUN+="/usr/bin/loginctl lock-session"
Finally I said: sudo udevadm control --reload
However, when I pull USB device out - nothing happens.
What I am doing wrong? I have Ubuntu 24.04.

This is a a guess based upon looking at man loginctl, but if /usr/bin/loginctl lock-session is changed to usr/bin/loginctl lock-sessions does it work? This is because I'm not sure what session identifier the udev rule runs as.

Yes! lock-sessions (plural) was the solution. Thanks!

From looking at man loginctl suggest change the RUN command from:
/usr/bin/loginctl lock-session

To:
/usr/bin/loginctl lock-sessions

I.e. lock-sessions plural. So the complete rule would be:
ACTION=="remove", ATTRS{PRODUCT}=="20a0/42b2/108", RUN+="/usr/bin/loginctl lock-sessions"

This is because without further research it isn't immediately clear which session identifier the udev rule runs as, but /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd runs as root so likely won't be in the same session as the logged in user.
Relevant output from the manual page:
       lock-session [ID...], unlock-session [ID...]
           Activates/deactivates the screen lock on one or more sessions, if
           the session supports it. Takes one or more session identifiers as
           arguments. If no argument is specified, the session of the caller
           is locked/unlocked.

           Added in version 233.

       lock-sessions, unlock-sessions
           Activates/deactivates the screen lock on all current sessions
           supporting it.

           Added in version 188.


So, the change should lock all current sessions.
